# How much is java used in 2d/3d indie games? (before/after Minecraft)

Tags: java, 2d, 3d

I wonder for my own use and curiosity, how popular is Java in indie game development ,
in 2d and 3d? Are there any good open/closed source games done in java?

Comment: Made the question clearer.

Comment: I really don't see why Minecraft has anything to do with it.

Comment: Minecraft somewhat "legitimized" Java as a game programming language in some peoples' eyes as it was probably one of the first ones that was highly successful.

Comment: @Tetrad, only people who were ignorant of Java usage in the games industry. I don't think Minecraft has yet made even a significant fraction of what RuneScape had already made 10 years ago.

Comment: Runescape is abandoning Java by WebGL, in exchange of ``much more sophisticated graphics for RuneScape``: http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57580221-93/its-about-time-runescape-dumps-java-for-html5

Comment: @JCM, it will still be using Java on the back end, and I wouldn't be surprised if the JS/WebGL front end is produced by source-to-source translation from Java (à la GWT, but given Jagex's NIH culture probably not actually GWT).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java is the language used for Android games. (I believe there may be some other methods like using C++ but its usually Java). If you have an Android phone, you can test the top-downloaded games to see good examples.

I think it's good for indie development - in fact I am doing an indie game for android. There are many tools that Google provides for you - such as debugger, emulator, memory allocation tracker. You can also use the Eclipse IDE with it.

There is also a lot of code online and the StackOverflow site if you get stuck on a bug. Also, Android supports openGL for 2D/3D games (though you can make a 2D game without it - as I am doing).

Comment: Yes, but outside of Android, its use and scope is somewhat small, as @ZorbaTHut points out.

Comment: Maybe so, but I only wish to inform user3689 that mobile game development with Android is an option to indie developers.

Comment: Many many games in android are done using C++. :)

Answer (score 14):

It's not terribly popular, in my experience. There's a few problems. First off, Java isn't the most efficient language around (though better than many think), but that lack of efficiency isn't really compensated for by ease of development. Second, running Java is kind of a pain - it's gotten better recently, but it's still tainted by Java's legendary growing pains. Third, Java hasn't had particularly good graphics support in-browser, and if you're outside the browser, you may as well use something else.

It's not really a matter of Java being bad. It's a matter of Java not being particularly good for any game-related niche, and other languages actually being good. The language that does everything in a mediocre fashion loses to the languages that do something well.

There's a list of [famous Java games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/famous-games-written-in-java) on this very site, but, well, you can see how popular it is.

Comment: So, instead of parroting common complains about java, please give links that support your position. In my experience, Java's efficiency is more than sufficient (say, using a good toolkit such as Xith3D or Ardor or somesuch) for almost any indie-caliber game. One overview of these myths is [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275.html?ca=dgr-jw22JavaUrbanLegends) or even from Stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c).

Comment: Running Java isn't difficult, and getting Java to bundle as a standalone app is probably as hard as making sure your user has the necessary support environment for any other language (see exej, jexepack, etc.). Why are you judging Java on its past "growing pains"? By that logic, C++ is probably a terrible choice for our industry.

Comment: 'Does everything in a mediocre fashion?'  Because of this statement I don't really believe you have ever written or deployed any Java code, and are probably not in the best position to issue such sweeping conclusions.

Comment: Did you actually read my post? Java does almost everything adequately, but it does nothing particularly well. I'm not saying it's a bad language, but people tend to focus on the languages that are very good. Java just doesn't stand out in any fashion. It's not superfast, it's not supereasy, it's not supercompatible, it's not supercontrollable, it doesn't have amazing access to third-party libraries. It's a solid B. Solid B's don't win.

Comment: Java is probably as fast as you need it to be, really easy to code if you've ever tried, and deploys to PC / Linux / Mac with almost no trouble.

Comment: As far as not being supercontrollable, that is a decision you make when you spec your game. If it needs it, don't use it. If it doesn't need such fine-grained control, use it. Regarding third party libraries... the Java 6 API is massive and implements a lot you would *need* third party libraries for in another language, especially C++ (which I use all the time). There are several libraries out there to help fill the gap, such as the ones @ChrisE mentioned.

Comment: Java has less third-party library support and is slower and less precise than C++, harder to code than Lua or Python, and is more difficult to run on enduser computers than either of those. Once again, I'm not saying it's a bad language at all, and I don't know why you're getting so indignant over this. All I'm saying is that it doesn't stand out in any particular way. It's capable but unexciting, and people tend to not code games in Java mostly because people don't code games in Java. It just doesn't have the network effects that the other languages more popular for games do.

Comment: It excels at readability, one of the most if not THE most critical attribute of a programming language.  You only write the code but it is read repeatedly, up to hundreds of times for long lasting code.  It is really strange how long it takes some people to figure this out.

Comment: It's not really any better at readability than any other language. Every language has its strengths and its weaknesses, and Java is no exception.

Comment: Java has reflection, and anyone that spends a lot of time using ASM/C/C++ will find themselves scared, yet infinitely appreciative of the productivity increases that modern languages like Java and C# provide.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite answering the question, but javagaming.org has a non-exhaustive list of commercial Java games [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,3123.msg192440.html).